# How can I refer to the "\0" term in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to implement the following, where *a and *b are constant chars:
''' 
while(*a != '\0' || *b != '\0')
'''
but I don't know how to refer to \0. Can I just refer to it as zero ?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. `'\0'` means the character with value zero.

Comment: `'\0'` is equivalent to `(char)0`; a narrow integer type with value zero.